# How can i send mulltiple images at once to server?

Tags: android, web-services, android-asynctask

i need to send three images at once to server, currently i can send one image by following code(PictureId). If i need to send three images say Picture1Id, Picture2Id, Picture3Id how can set in (protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {})

```
// IMAGE UPLOAD ///////////
                final ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(NBCompetitorTracking_Activity.this);
                progress.setMessage("Uploading image, please wait...");

                // If auto upload true upload picture:
                if (new SessionManager(NBCompetitorTracking_Activity.this).isAutoUpload()) {
                    // upload image

                    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                        @Override
                        protected void onPreExecute() {
                            super.onPreExecute();
                            progress.show();

                        }

                        @Override
                        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                            UploadImage.uploadImage(NB_CompetitorTracking.**PictureId**);
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            super.onPostExecute(result);
                            progress.dismiss();
                        }

                    };

                }
                // END: IMAGE UPLOAD ///////////
```

Comment: Your problem is not quite clear, why can't you send the images in three calls? Or maybe you could pass a List of images to the file uploader?

Comment: @prmottajr How can i call three times..can you please suggest me..

Comment: What is the code that triggers the upload? Do you select many images or click on them? How the pictureIds are selected?

Comment: @prmottajr There is a switch in my settings, if we set "yes" it should  automatically upload to the server when we take a picture from camera..

Comment: @prmottajr I am asking that if i need to set three images say Picture1Id, Picture2Id, Picture3Id, how can call three pictureId's at once

Answer (score 1):

Start multiple Thread instances of the 'upload thread' with separate files to be uploaded.
Purely upon java concept, You can write a Thread class that uploads a file. And initiate many instances(as much as the files) and start them all together.